# Yii Validation rule for decimal range

Tags: php, validation, yii

I want create a rule for decimal range value 40.000<= score_percentage <=100.000

```
array('entrance_score', 'compare','operator'=>'<=','compareValue'=>100, 'message'=>'Maximum Entrance Score should be 100.' ),
```

While testing from GUI, it make acceptable the decimal number less than 100 but cannot make acceptable more or equal to 40.000.

The following rule is not working properly, so what should I do?

```
array('entrance_score', 'compare','operator'=>'>=','compareValue'=>0 , 'message'=>'Minimum Entrance Score should be 40.' ),
```

Comment: i see a typo in your second rule, `'compareValue'=>0` instead of expected `'compareValue'=>40`

Answer (score 2):

So, you want to place a check so that `entrance_score` value is between `40.000` and `100.000`, right ?

You could just place a `min`, `max` rule in your model, something like:

```
array('entrance_score', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>false, 'min'=>40, 'max'=>100),
```

or, you could create your own custom validation rule, like:

```
public function rules()
    {
        return array(
            //............
            array('entrance_score', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>false),
            array('entrance_score', 'authenticate'),
            //.....
        );
    }
```

and your `authenticate` function:

```
public function authenticate($attribute,$params)
    {
        if($this->entrance_score < 40) {
            $this->addError('entrance_score','Minimum Entrance Score should be 40.');
        } elseif($this->entrance_score > 100) {
            $this->addError('entrance_score','Maximum Entrance Score should be 100.');
        }
    }
```

that should do it.

Comment: 'integer' instead of 'numerical' for Yii2.